# como hacer un join a tabla pivote?

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, join

Que tal amigo alguien me puede apoyar como hacer un join desde una tabla normal a una tabla pivote las tablas son:
* ordenes
* productos
*OrdenPorducto (tabla pivote)

lo que tengo que hacer es un join de ordenes a OrdenProducto donde el id de la orden y el id del producto se encuentre en OrdenProducto. Espero haber explicado bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno espero que esto te ayude...

Primero en tu **modelo** para tu tabla **pivot OrdenProducto** debes de crear 2 funciones:
una para orden y otra para producto

```
public function orden()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Orden', 'foreign_key');
}

public function producto()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Producto', 'foreign_key');
}
```

Luego de esto en tu controlador **OrdenProductoController**

Llamamos a nuestro modelo **OrdenProducto**

```
Use OrdenProducto
```

Y en tu funcion tienes que hacer lo siguiente

```
public function index(){
 $orden_prod = OrdenProducto::with('orden','producto');
 return view('tuvista',compact('$orden_prod'));
}
```

Luego en tu vista

```
@foreach($orden_prod as $op)
 //Si quieres obtener el nombre de un producto
    $op->producto->name;
 //De la misma forma si quieres obtener la fecha de la orden
    $op->orden->fecha 
@endforeach
```